# How to access ACR images from calico.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, calico

I have a k3s cluster with calico pods `calico-node-xxx` & `calico-kube-controllers-xxx` running in kube-system namespace. I am using [calico.yaml](https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml) config in my project.

Now, I want these images in calico.yaml to be pulled from my ACR repo instead of `docker.io` repo.  So I tagged & pushed these images in my ACR repo and changed the images path in calico manifest yaml file (for e.g. `myacrrepo.io/calico/node:v3.17.1` ), so that pods can pull image from ACR repo.

But where should I mention credentials of ACR repo in calico manifest file, as without credential (username/password/hostname) the pod is failing with error `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

Can someone let me know that where in [calico.yaml](https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml), ACR repo credential shall I add (and what is the syntax for providing credential in `calico.yaml` because for dockr.io images no credentials are mentioned in `calico.yaml` which I can replace with my ACR repo credentials) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a private container registry then you have to create an imagePullSecret. Microsoft explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes) on how to do that for ACR.

Once you have created the imagePullSecret add it to the `pod spec` as outlined the section 'Use the image pull secret' of the documenation.

This imagePullSecret is not necessary for docker.io, since docker.io is a public registry and imagePullSecrets are only needed for private registries.